# Custom Toolbar shows addbarbuttonitem in lower to its border ?? not properly aligned

Tags: ios7

> -(void)viewDidLoad

{

> [super viewDidLoad];
>     self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO;
>    tableViewDataSourceMutableArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ONE", @"TWO", >@"THREE", @"FOUR", @"FIVE", nil];
>     self.totalData=tableViewDataSourceMutableArray.count;

```
//Adding Custome Back Navigation Button
```

> UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
>    UIButton *backButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
>   [backButton setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
>   backButton.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,img.size.width,img.size.height);
>   [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
>   UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
>   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=customBarItem;

Comment: //Adding Right Bar Add Button
    UIBarButtonItem *addBarButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertData)];
    
    
    UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180.0,0, 100, 30)];
    toolBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    toolBar.tintColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    toolBar.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
   
    
    NSArray *items=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.editButtonItem,addBarButton,nil];

Comment: [toolBar setItems:items];
    UIBarButtonItem *barItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toolBar];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=barItem;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden=YES;
    
    
    //Addding TextBox to TitleItem of NavigationController
    
    headingTextField=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 8, 100, 30)];
    headingTextField.backgroundColor=[UIColor magentaColor];

Comment: [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:headingTextField];
    headingTextField.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
    self.headingTextField.delegate=self;
    self.headingTextField.placeholder=@"Heading ..!!";